# Save result from register into array[1000] without user input each time

Tags: c, code-composer

Here is the Sample Code I am using,

```
#include <msp430.h>

int main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;               // Stop WDT

    // GPIO Setup
    P1OUT &= ~BIT0;                         // Clear LED to start
    P1DIR |= BIT0;                          // Set P1.0/LED to output
    P1SEL1 |= BIT1;                         // Configure P1.1 for ADC
    P1SEL0 |= BIT1;

    // Disable the GPIO power-on default high-impedance mode to activate
    // previously configured port settings
    PM5CTL0 &= ~LOCKLPM5;

    // Configure ADC12
    ADC12CTL0 = ADC12SHT0_2 | ADC12ON;      // Sampling time, S&H=16, ADC12 on
    ADC12CTL1 = ADC12SHP;                   // Use sampling timer
    ADC12CTL2 |= ADC12RES_2;                // 12-bit conversion results
    ADC12MCTL0 |= ADC12INCH_1;              // A1 ADC input select; Vref=AVCC
    ADC12IER0 |= ADC12IE0;                  // Enable ADC conv complete interrupt

    while (1)
    {
        __delay_cycles(5000);
        ADC12CTL0 |= ADC12ENC | ADC12SC;    // Start sampling/conversion

        __bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits | GIE); // LPM0, ADC12_ISR will force exit
        __no_operation();                   // For debugger
    }
}

#if defined(__TI_COMPILER_VERSION__) || defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__)
#pragma vector = ADC12_VECTOR
__interrupt void ADC12_ISR(void)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
void __attribute__ ((interrupt(ADC12_VECTOR))) ADC12_ISR (void)
#else
#error Compiler not supported!
#endif
{
    switch(__even_in_range(ADC12IV, ADC12IV_ADC12RDYIFG))
    {
        case ADC12IV_NONE:        break;    // Vector  0:  No interrupt
        case ADC12IV_ADC12OVIFG:  break;    // Vector  2:  ADC12MEMx Overflow
        case ADC12IV_ADC12TOVIFG: break;    // Vector  4:  Conversion time overflow
        case ADC12IV_ADC12HIIFG:  break;    // Vector  6:  ADC12BHI
        case ADC12IV_ADC12LOIFG:  break;    // Vector  8:  ADC12BLO
        case ADC12IV_ADC12INIFG:  break;    // Vector 10:  ADC12BIN
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG0:             // Vector 12:  ADC12MEM0 Interrupt
            if (ADC12MEM0 >= 0x7ff)         // ADC12MEM0 = A1 > 0.5AVcc?
                P1OUT |= BIT0;              // P1.0 = 1
            else
                P1OUT &= ~BIT0;             // P1.0 = 0

                // Exit from LPM0 and continue executing main
                __bic_SR_register_on_exit(LPM0_bits);
            break;
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG1:   break;    // Vector 14:  ADC12MEM1
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG2:   break;    // Vector 16:  ADC12MEM2
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG3:   break;    // Vector 18:  ADC12MEM3
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG4:   break;    // Vector 20:  ADC12MEM4
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG5:   break;    // Vector 22:  ADC12MEM5
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG6:   break;    // Vector 24:  ADC12MEM6
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG7:   break;    // Vector 26:  ADC12MEM7
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG8:   break;    // Vector 28:  ADC12MEM8
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG9:   break;    // Vector 30:  ADC12MEM9
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG10:  break;    // Vector 32:  ADC12MEM10
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG11:  break;    // Vector 34:  ADC12MEM11
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG12:  break;    // Vector 36:  ADC12MEM12
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG13:  break;    // Vector 38:  ADC12MEM13
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG14:  break;    // Vector 40:  ADC12MEM14
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG15:  break;    // Vector 42:  ADC12MEM15
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG16:  break;    // Vector 44:  ADC12MEM16
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG17:  break;    // Vector 46:  ADC12MEM17
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG18:  break;    // Vector 48:  ADC12MEM18
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG19:  break;    // Vector 50:  ADC12MEM19
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG20:  break;    // Vector 52:  ADC12MEM20
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG21:  break;    // Vector 54:  ADC12MEM21
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG22:  break;    // Vector 56:  ADC12MEM22
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG23:  break;    // Vector 58:  ADC12MEM23
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG24:  break;    // Vector 60:  ADC12MEM24
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG25:  break;    // Vector 62:  ADC12MEM25
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG26:  break;    // Vector 64:  ADC12MEM26
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG27:  break;    // Vector 66:  ADC12MEM27
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG28:  break;    // Vector 68:  ADC12MEM28
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG29:  break;    // Vector 70:  ADC12MEM29
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG30:  break;    // Vector 72:  ADC12MEM30
        case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG31:  break;    // Vector 74:  ADC12MEM31
        case ADC12IV_ADC12RDYIFG: break;    // Vector 76:  ADC12RDY
        default: break;
    }
}
```

Here is the modified version, which I cannot make it to work.

```
#include <msp430.h>
int i = 0;
int result[1000];
int main(void)
{
 WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;         // Stop WDT
 // GPIO Setup
 P1OUT &= ~BIT0;              // Clear LED to start
 P1DIR |= BIT0;              // P1.0 output
 P1SEL1 |= BIT1;              // Configure P1.1 for ADC
 P1SEL0 |= BIT1;
 // Disable the GPIO power-on default high-impedance mode to activate
 // previously configured port settings
 PM5CTL0 &= ~LOCKLPM5;   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// COMMON FOR ALL PURPOSE
 // By default, REFMSTR=1 => REFCTL is used to configure the internal reference
 while(REFCTL0 & REFGENBUSY);       // If ref generator busy, WAIT
 REFCTL0 |= REFVSEL_0 | REFON;       // Select internal ref = 1.2V ///////////////////// FOR ADC12 REF VOLTAGE
                      // Internal Reference ON
 // Configure ADC12
 ADC12CTL0 = ADC12SHT0_2 | ADC12ON;                                 /////////////////// ADC CONFIGURATION
 ADC12CTL1 = ADC12SHP;           // ADCCLK = MODOSC; sampling timer
 ADC12CTL2 |= ADC12RES_2;         // 12-bit conversion results
 ADC12IER0 |= ADC12IE0;          // Enable ADC conv complete interrupt
 ADC12MCTL0 |= ADC12INCH_1 | ADC12VRSEL_1; // A1 ADC input select; Vref=1.2V
 while(!(REFCTL0 & REFGENRDY));      // Wait for reference generator
                      // to settle
  ADC12CTL0 |= ADC12ENC | ADC12SC;     // Sampling and conversion start
  __bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits + GIE);   // LPM0, ADC10_ISR will force exit

}


 #if defined(__TI_COMPILER_VERSION__) || defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__)
#pragma vector = ADC12_VECTOR
__interrupt void ADC12_ISR(void)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
void __attribute__ ((interrupt(ADC12_VECTOR))) ADC12_ISR (void)
#else
#error Compiler not supported!
#endif
{
 switch (__even_in_range(ADC12IV, ADC12IV_ADC12RDYIFG))
 {
  case ADC12IV_NONE:    break;    // Vector 0: No interrupt
  case ADC12IV_ADC12OVIFG: break;    // Vector 2: ADC12MEMx Overflow
  case ADC12IV_ADC12TOVIFG: break;    // Vector 4: Conversion time overflow
  case ADC12IV_ADC12HIIFG: break;    // Vector 6: ADC12BHI
  case ADC12IV_ADC12LOIFG: break;    // Vector 8: ADC12BLO
  case ADC12IV_ADC12INIFG: break;    // Vector 10: ADC12BIN
  case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG0:         // Vector 12: ADC12MEM0 Interrupt
    if(i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
     //result[i] = ADC12MEM0;
      ADC12CTL0 |= ADC12ENC | ADC12SC; // Sampling and conversion start
    }
    else{
        ADC12CTL0 &= ~ADC12ENC;
    }
   //result = ADC12MEM0;
   //ADC12CTL0 |= ADC12ENC | ADC12SC;
   break;                // Clear CPUOFF bit from 0(SR)
  default: break;
 }
}
```

So, this is the MSP430FR6989's sample code for ADC I'm trying to modify. I want to save the conversion result stored into the register ADC12MEM0 into the int result[1000]; with the if statement. However, I feel like I'm missing some pieces and it also doesn't run my code and gives error message.

**I have just recently been learning about C language from YouTube, and all the tutorials of array i came across were using printf and scanf's with storing values from user input. In my case, I don't need the user input. I need stored value saved into array without the user input for 1000 times. What am I missing here? and where can I find information about my case?

```
 case ADC12IV_ADC12IFG0:         // Vector 12: ADC12MEM0 Interrupt
    if(i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
     //result[i] = ADC12MEM0;
      ADC12CTL0 |= ADC12ENC | ADC12SC; // Sampling and conversion start
    }
    else{
        ADC12CTL0 &= ~ADC12ENC;
    }
   //result = ADC12MEM0;
   //ADC12CTL0 |= ADC12ENC | ADC12SC;
   break;                // Clear CPUOFF bit from 0(SR)
  default: break;
```

Comment: You may want to use a timer.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do with `if(i = 0; i < 1000; i++){`...`else`. I assume that is supposed to be a `for` loop to write 1000 times into `result[i]`, but I don't understand what circumstance the `else` is supposed to be used.

Comment: Doing 1000 operations in an interrupt handler isn't always such a good idea.

Comment: @Jay - You didn't post sample code for ADC, you rather posted code you already modified and defaced. This makes it next to impossible for someone without specific knowledge of the hardware to point out the needed changes.

Comment: @EdmCoff
 else{
       ADC12CTL0 &= ~ADC12ENC;
}
I'm thinking that this will stop the ADC conversions once i hits 1000

Comment: I'd suggest looking into using a DMA to get these 1000 samples, rather 1024 samples just for power of two benefits.

Comment: @Armali Sorry! This is my first time using stackoverflow. I will improve my postings in the future.  Here is the sample code I am using! https://dev.ti.com/tirex/explore/node?node=AFw.3kJqshBDRoqd2-qdgQ__IOGqZri__LATEST

Comment: @Sorenp Is the DMA something I will have to connect to my microcontroller using wires? If so can I achieve this with breadboard and its wires?

Comment: @Jay DMA is usually a built-in peripheral just like ADC / DAC / SPI etc. check your MCU data sheet to see if it is available.

Answer (score 0):

I'd replace the sample code's `while (1)` with `for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)`, i. e. keep the code structure which loops in `main` and handles one conversion interrupt at a time in `ADC12_ISR`. There you'd just have to insert `result[i] = ADC12MEM0;` before `// Exit from LPM0 and continue executing main`.